# How can I find the git version of a source code dump?

Tags: git, version-control

A commercial company has forked an open source project and added their own command line options. My problem is that the fork was a long time ago and I'd like to update the code to take advantage of new features.

Given that they have complied with the GPL and released an archive of the modified source, how can I **best** determine the git version they branched from?

Comment: Do you have internal git repository available or just some tarball?

Comment: @anydot It is just a tarball which is the problem. No trace of any version control.

Comment: Can you ask the company?  Presumably they used some version control system and can look it up for you.

Comment: @RichardHansen I have asked as that would be the simplest method, however so far there has been no response.

Answer (score 4):

Since you need to find it against just a tarball, the best guess for the fork-point would be to find commit which has minimal diff against your tarball.

If you think that your fork started from some released, tagged version you can use this:

1. Import your tarball to some branch (you don't need to publish it anywhere of course)
2. Switch to that branch
3. Run this command:

> `eval "git for-each-ref --shell --format 'echo -n %(objectname) " "; git diff %(objectname) --minimal | wc -l' refs/tags" | sort -n -k 2 -r | tail`

This command will print commit name in the first column, in the second column number of changed lines (approximately, since it also counts diff's header but that shouldn't change much), sorted by number of changed lines. Your fork-point should be the last line there.

How this works: it run git diff between every tag and your tarball input, with unified format, without any context and count lines of this diff. Then it's sorted by this number of lines changed.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the last commit id before your company started editing (the fork point).

then find that commit id in the os repo.

then i'd suggest to diff the most current commits of both repos, patch the changes from your companies repo and try and apply it to the os repo in a new branch. fix a few conflicts, test, test, test, and hopefully your good!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to the Git repositories of the original open source project and the commercial fork, you can use `git merge-base`:

```
git merge-base original_project/master commercial_fork/master
```

This will find the most recent common ancestor of both `original_project/master` `commercial_fork/master`.  The output of this command is the Git revision the fork is currently derived from.  You can use `git describe` or `git tag --contains` to try to identify the project version corresponding to that Git revision.